# How to remove a specific element from an array in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have an array of multiple types `( Int32 | Char | String )` and need to remove a specific element.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Array(T).delete_at(index)](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.4/Array.html#delete_at%28index%3AInt%29-instance-method) to delete an element at a given index in your array, or [Array(T).delete(obj)](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.4/Array.html#delete%28obj%29-instance-method) that deletes all elements in the array that are equal to *obj*

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Shree's now deleted answer

`new_arr = arr.reject{ |element| element == "whatever"}` or could use `reject!`